# getElementById function $(#...) is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following page working except one thing.
It cannot find element (div) with id of "result_set".
But setting its "html" property does work.
I cannot understand WTF...
All other elements are working fine.

I need to .appendChild() to that node but it throws "no function" error.
But i can set "html" at the same time....

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='main-form' method="POST">
  <input id="cmd-data" type="submit" value="Обновить">
</form>
<br>
<div id="result_set">result goes here</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#main-form").submit(function() {
    //         $("#loading").show().fadeIn('slow');
    //           $("#result_set").hide().fadeOut('slow');

    var frm = $('#main-form');
    var vname = $("#tracking-id").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: frm.attr('method'),
      url: 'dataPage.php',
      data: '{"call_method": "method_name"}',
      success: function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        data = JSON.parse(data[1]);

        str_buf = "";
        //           var new_table = document.createElement("table");
        //           $("#result_set").appendChild(new_table);

        var hdr_done = false;

        data.forEach(function(element) {

          //                   var new_row = document.createElement("tr");
          //                   new_table.appendChild(new_row);

          let sub_str_buf = "";

          if (!hdr_done) {
            for (let val of Object.keys(element)) {
              sub_str_buf += "<th>" + val + "</th>";
            }
            str_buf += "<tr>" + sub_str_buf + "</tr>";
            hdr_done = true;
          }

          sub_str_buf = "";
          for (let val of Object.values(element)) {
            sub_str_buf += "<td>" + val + "</td>";
          }

          str_buf += "<tr>" + sub_str_buf + "</tr>";

          $("#result_set").slideDown();
        });

        // Next string works
        $("#result_set").html("<table>" + str_buf + "</table>");
        // Next string fails with "id() is not a function". ANY DOMElement function here will fail.
        console.log($("#result_set").id());


      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(" The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Do not add spam text to your post to get around the requirement that asks you to explain more of the problem - instead, please *actually explain the problem in more detail*, such as what sort of debugging you've tried that isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple.

.getElementById() in common JS and $(#..) in jQuery make the same.
BUT first one returns DOMElement and second one - jQuery object.

That is why you cannot call appendChild().
Just call jQuery methods .append() or appendTo() and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

`id` is not a function - it's an attribute:

```
console.log($("#result_set").id);
```

Comment: Does not work. Actually i need .appendChild() but it does not work either.

Comment: I think it would either need to be `$('#result_set')[0].id` or `$('#result_set').attr('id')` to work at all. But that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. This line works fine: var frm = $('#main-form'); So it returns single object since #... is defining unique element ID ...